# Using if else statement with radio buttons in javascript

Tags: javascript, if-statement, radio-button

I am trying to use an if else statement to do a certain action if one radio button is selected and do a different action if another is selected.  In this case I want to use one formula if the basic button is selected and the pro formula if the pro button is selected. I am new to programming so apologies in advanced.

```
<html>

<head>

<title>Calculator</title>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function packageTotal(){
    //Enter in prices here
    var x = 5;
    var y = 10;
    var p = x + y*12;
    var b = y * 12;

    if(document.calculator.getElementById('basicProgram').checked) {
        //Basic package is checked
        document.calculator.total.value=b;


    }else if(document.calculator.getElementById('proProgram').checked) {
        //Pro package is checked
        document.calculator.total.value=p;

    } 

</head>

<body>

<!-- Opening a HTML Form. --> 
<form name="calculator">

<!-- User fills out form here -->

<br />
<input type="radio" name="programType" id="basicProgram" value="Basic" /> Basic
<input type="radio" name="programType" id="proProgram" value="Pro" checked /> Pro

<!-- Here result will be displayed. -->

<br />
Your total price is: <input type="text" name="total">


<input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="javascript:packageTotal();">


</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There were some typos.. which I fixed. Here is the [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Pn6X7/).

Comment: Thank you very very much! Problem is resolved!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your javascript is missing a `}`

```
<html>

<head>
<title>Calculator</title>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function packageTotal() {
    // Enter in prices here
    var x = 5;
    var y = 10;
    var p = x + y * 12;
    var b = y * 12;

    if (document.getElementById('basicProgram').checked) {
        // Basic package is checked
        document.calculator.total.value = b;

    } else if (document.getElementById('proProgram').checked) {
        // Pro package is checked
        document.calculator.total.value = p;

    }
}
</script>
</head>

<body>

<!-- Opening a HTML Form. --> 
<form name="calculator">

<!-- User fills out form here -->

<br />
<input type="radio" name="programType" id="basicProgram" value="Basic" /> Basic
<input type="radio" name="programType" id="proProgram" value="Pro" checked /> Pro

<!-- Here result will be displayed. -->

<br />
Your total price is: <input type="text" name="total">


<input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="javascript:packageTotal();">


</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://plnkr.co/edit/I93dS1iVxPJH7GPeDy7O?p=preview)

Comment: why return false ? that is button

Comment: @MohammadMasoudian missed that

Answer (score 0):

Inside of your function packageTotal() you will also want to write:

```
//stop the form from submitting
//place this wherever you need it in your logic
return false;
```

I also think you are interested in adding onChange() to the radio buttons instead of the onSubmit method:

```
<input type="radio" name="programType" id="basicProgram" value="Basic" onChange="packageTotal()" /> Basic
<input type="radio" name="programType" id="proProgram" value="Pro" checked onChange="packageTotal()" /> Pro
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>

<head>

<title>Calculator</title>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function packageTotal(){
    //Enter in prices here
    var x = 5;
    var y = 10;
    var p = x + y*12;
    var b = y * 12;

    if(document.getElementById('basicProgram').checked) {
        //Basic package is checked
        document.calculator.total.value=b;


    }else if(document.getElementById('proProgram').checked) {
        //Pro package is checked
        document.calculator.total.value=p;

    } 
}
</head>

<body>

<!-- Opening a HTML Form. --> 
<form name="calculator">

<!-- User fills out form here -->

<br />
<input type="radio" name="programType" id="basicProgram" value="Basic" /> Basic
<input type="radio" name="programType" id="proProgram" value="Pro" checked /> Pro

<!-- Here result will be displayed. -->

<br />
Your total price is: <input type="text" name="total">


<input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="javascript:packageTotal();">


</form>

</body>
</html>
```